# Post uploaded file using requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I receive a file from a HTML form  in Flask and want to post it to another service using Requests.  In the destination service, the incoming request doesn't contain the file.  How do I post an uploaded file?

```
f = request.files['file']
sendFile = {"file": FileStorage(filename=f.filename, stream=f.stream, content_type=f.content_type, content_length=actualSize)}

c = checksumMD5(f.stream)
r = requests.post("http://myservicedotcom/upload", files=sendFile,
                  headers={"X-Auth-Token":token, "Checksum":checksumMD5(f.stream), "File-Size":actualSize})
```

Comment: Where did you read that you had to use `FileStorage()` here?

Comment: Isn't that a file-like object? In the destination service it always reads a file storage

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to wrap your uploaded file in a `FileStorage` instance; that's an implementation detail of Werkzeug (the library underpinning Flask).

Instead, you need to *rewind your stream* after creating a checksum:

```
f = request.files['file']
c = checksumMD5(f.stream)
f.seek(0)

sendFile = {"file": (f.filename, f.stream, f.mimetype)}

r = requests.post("http://myservicedotcom/upload", files=sendFile,
                  headers={"X-Auth-Token": token, "Checksum": c, "File-Size": actualSize})
```

Comment: What's the purpose of that seek(0) ?

Comment: @Urbester: file objects have a read/write position; it starts at 0, and as you read data it advances so that the file object knows where to start reading next if you only read part of the file, or where to start writing if you write data to the file object. `f.tell()` gives you that position, and `f.seek(0)` sets it back to the start.

Comment: @Urbester: since you need to read the data to create a checksum, you almost certainly never reset the read position, so when `requests.post()` tries to read from the file an empty string is returned.